# Get objects in the other part of a N-N relationship that are not related to the actual object

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I have a N-N relationship between **Films** and **Genres**, and I am trying to get from a `$film` the objects in the table **Genres** that are **NOT** in `$film->genres()`.

I have looked for trying to do something like `Genres:all() - $film->genres()` or to do a loop in order to erase everyone but there is no [Collection](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/collections) method that allows me to do that.

How can I do that?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the solution:

```
$film = Film::findOrFail(1);
$hasGenres = $film->genres()->pluck('id');
$doesntHaveGenres = Genres::whereNotIn('id',$hasGenres)->get();
```